# How to manage duplicates whith multiple managed packages integrations

Tags: trigger, managed-package, integration, duplicate-management, record

In my org there are many managed packages(at least 4 - Hubspot, Apollo, Leadfeeder, Calendly), that can insert Contacts and manipulate them afterwards. Sometimes there is an issue with records duplicated by different packages.

**Example:**

Hubspot creates it's own Contact when someones fills the form on the website,then Apollo also pushes record of the same person to Salesforce, which is in fact duplicate but created from different source.

Is it possible to merge/clean up duplicates created by these integrations, but keep them working(able to push record updates) at the same time ?

Comment: Take a look at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management

Comment: You will have to check with those vendors to see how they support Salesforce matching and duplicate rules.